# Trying to use S3 to upload files via React on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

so I'm following this article https://medium.com/@andrea.wayte/using-amazon-s3-to-store-images-for-react-on-rails-b1414ba2c0b2. Whenever I'm at the part where she migrates her database after updating the database I get this error.

```
admins-MBP:direct-s3-example admin$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
/Users/admin/direct-s3-example/config/environments/development.rb:65:in `<main>'
/Users/admin/direct-s3-example/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I don't have an environment.rb file but here's my development.rb file.

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  # Run rails dev:cache to toggle caching.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
    config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Highlight code that triggered database queries in logs.
  config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
  config.assets.quiet = true

  # Raises error for missing translations.
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end

Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_host_name: 's3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
    s3_credentials: {
       bucket: ENV.fetch('petition-form'),
       access_key_id: ENV.fetch('--------'),
       secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('--------------'),
       s3_region: ENV.fetch('us-east-2'),
    }
}
```

Comment: Try placing the whole block of code at the bottom (starting with  `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"`) before the word `end`. `config` is accessible inside the block passed to `Rails.application.configure` but you currently are using it outside this block

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered. The code at the bottom was past the last `end`